# Not able to use colors other than white or black in stroke object

Tags: android

I am adding a boundary for my layout but its not allowing me define the color other than white or black. Weird! This is a code snippet of boundary.xml in resource folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own colors in colors.xml, and then use them in your drawable as `@color/mycolor`
You can also use directly color codes for the android:color attribute, like #F00, #4F00 (contains alpha channel), #FF0000 or #44FF0000 (again, has alpha channel)

Answer (score 0):

try hex value for color

```
 android:color="#FF00FF00"
```

Answer (score 0):

use your custom colors, first stored in colors.xml file in values and then get those values for usage..
or set like this

```
android:color="#FF0000"
```